# Python: 3D column-major tensor to row-major

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I use `scipy.io` to read in a Mat File into python, loading a 3D tensor. Most references I find online only discuss 2 dimensions, and I am having difficulty wrapping my head around column major to row major in data with dimensions more than 2.

1. Does scipy.io handle the conversion from column major (order = 'F') to row major (order = 'C') automatically?
2. if not 1, is there a better way to change a 3D tensor than using a combination of `ravel` and `reshape` with `order`?
3. if not 2, is there a way to programatically determine the shape the converted tensor should be? In the example below, I use unravel and reshape, but it is clear that the original shape is inappropriate?

**EXAMPLE**

In this example, say I have a (2, 4, 3) dimensional matrix that was read in in Column-Major, and I want to reverse it to Row-Major.

```
import numpy as np

lst3d = [[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]], [[13, 14, 15], [17, 18, 19], [21, 22, 23], [25, 26, 27]]]

print(lst3d)
a = np.array(lst3d)
b = np.array(lst3d)

print(a.shape)
print('----------')
print(a.ravel(order='C').reshape(a.shape))
print('----------')
print(b.ravel(order='F').reshape(b.shape))
```

outputs:

```
[[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]], [[13, 14, 15], [17, 18, 19], [21, 22, 23], [25, 26, 27]]]
(2, 4, 3)
----------
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]]

 [[13 14 15]
  [17 18 19]
  [21 22 23]
  [25 26 27]]]
----------
[[[ 0 13  3]
  [17  6 21]
  [ 9 25  1]
  [14  4 18]]

 [[ 7 22 10]
  [26  2 15]
  [ 5 19  8]
  [23 11 27]]]
```

**RELATED**

- [numpy array row major and column major](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341614/numpy-array-row-major-and-column-major?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/vignettes/arrays.html
- https://craftofcoding.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/column-major-vs-row-major-arrays-does-it-matter/

Comment: I wrote a long answer to [Writing a 3d numpy array that is readable in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053572).  See it addresses your issues.  I point out that there are 2 significant differences: the axis order, and the display style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Octave:

```
>> x=0:23;
>> x=reshape(x,2,4,3);
>> x
x =
ans(:,:,1) =
   0   2   4   6
   1   3   5   7
ans(:,:,2) =
    8   10   12   14
    9   11   13   15
ans(:,:,3) =
   16   18   20   22
   17   19   21   23
>> save -v7 test3d x
```

In ipython:

```
In [192]: data = io.loadmat('test3d')
In [194]: x=data['x']
In [195]: x
Out[195]: 
array([[[ 0.,  8., 16.],
        [ 2., 10., 18.],
        [ 4., 12., 20.],
        [ 6., 14., 22.]],

       [[ 1.,  9., 17.],
        [ 3., 11., 19.],
        [ 5., 13., 21.],
        [ 7., 15., 23.]]])
In [196]: x.shape
Out[196]: (2, 4, 3)
```

Displayed as in Octave:

```
In [197]: x[:,:,0]
Out[197]: 
array([[0., 2., 4., 6.],
       [1., 3., 5., 7.]])
```

`loadmat` has loaded it as `F` order, with the same 2,4,3 shape.  And the right `ravel` produces the original 0:23 numbers:

```
In [200]: x.ravel(order='F')
Out[200]: 
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.,
       13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23.])
```

The transpose of `x` produces a (3,4,2) order 'C' array:

```
In [207]: x.T[0]
Out[207]: 
array([[0., 1.],
       [2., 3.],
       [4., 5.],
       [6., 7.]])
In [208]: y=np.arange(24).reshape(3,4,2)
In [209]: y[0]
Out[209]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
```